# Find quadratic equation given two points and y-intersection

Tags: quadratics

Let the domain be $x \in [0,h]$. We have three points, $(0,1)$, $(h/2,0)$ and $(h,0)$.
How do I find the quadratic equation?

My attempt: I know that the roots are located at $x=h/2$ and $x=h$. Thus the equation must be of the form $(x-h/2)(x-h) = 0$.

Expanding out we have $x^2 - (h/2)x - hx + h^2 /2 =x^2 - (3h/2)x + h^2 /2 = 0$.

I'm not sure what to do with the y-intersection.

Comment: The equation has the form $c(x-h/2)(x-h)$, or $c(2x-h)(x-h)$, where $c$ is a constant, which you can adjust with the $y$-intercept.

Comment: _"Thus the equation must be of the form $(x−h/2)(x−h) = 0$"_ - no, because you don't know that the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation must be of the form $a(x-\frac{h}{2})(x-h)$ with $a \neq 0$. Using the point $(0,1)$ we get that
$$
 a \cdot \left(-\frac{h}{2}\right) \cdot (-h) = 1,
$$
so $a = 2/h^2$ (assuming that $h > 0$).

Answer (score 0):

You are close. The quadratic is of the shape $y=A(x-h/2)(x-h)$, where $A$ is a constant.

Use the point $(0,1)$ to identify $A$.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! But I don't see the logic of multiplying by a constant, instead of, say, adding a constant? I just don't `see' it.

Comment: Multiplying $(x-h/2)(x-h)$ by a constant does not change the roots. Adding a non-zero constant does.